# Comment file line in pull request with Github API

Tags: github, github-api, pull-request

I am writing an application and I need to comment a file from pull request using GitHUb API. There is a github repository and a pull request to it. In this pull request one file is modified. I'd like to comment a specific line in this file using GitHub API. The problem is, that while we are using github API to create comment, we are passing the number of line in the diff file, not in the actual one. So, I am asking if there any way to pass an actual file line number to create a comment for it. Here is a link to GitHub API request I'am trying to use: [Create a comment](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/comments/#create-a-comment)

Comment: It is very hard to understand what you're trying to do. Could you clarify, or possibly add an example?

Comment: Ok, I'll try to explain better, sorry. There is a github repository and a pull request to it. In this pull request one file is modified. I'd like to comment a specific line in this file using GitHub API. The problem is, that while we are using github API to create comment, we are passing the number of line in the diff file, not in the actual one. So, I am asking if there any way to pass an actual file line number to create a comment for it. Here is a link to GitHub API request I'am trying to use: https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/comments/#create-a-comment

Answer (score 1):

> So, I am asking if there any way to pass an actual file line number to create a comment for it.

That's not possible currently.

Pull request review comments are indeed comments created on lines of the diff, not lines of files. You can't comment on any line of any file in the pull request -- it needs to be a line in the diff. This behavior of the API matches the behavior on github.com -- give it a try and you won't be able to create a comment on any line in a file.

Also, if a line is changed in a file -- that line is shown two times in the diff: first the before (-), and then the after (+). So, it's not clear what you mean when you want to comment on a specific line in a file -- do you want to comment on the "old" line or the "new" line? Finally, how do you even know that a particular line of a file was changed in a pull request without viewing the diff?

My suggestion would be that you fetch the diff for the pull request, display that to the user and ask them to comment on a line of the diff. (This is basically what happens in the pull request UI on github.com). Is there a particular reason why that approach wouldn't work for you?

Comment: So can we use the API to comment on a line in the unified diff?  I only see ways to comment on a line in a diff of a commit or reply to comments in the PR.  I want to make a new comment on a line in the unified diff of a PR.

Comment: @JustinHarris Yep, it's possible: use this API: https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/comments/

Comment: Thanks but I only see https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/comments/#create-a-comment that's relevant.  I want to create a new comment so what should I use for the commit_id?

Comment: @JustinHarris try using the SHA of the most recent commit of the PR's head branch.

Comment: Hi @JustinHarris. I'm trying to do just this! Is it possible to comment on the PR as a whole and not a specific line in a specific file?

Comment: @deborah-digges Yep, it's possible, but the way you do that is that you create an issue comment for that pull request: https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/comments/#create-a-comment The `:number` you need to use is the number of the pull request. Also see this guide: https://developer.github.com/guides/working-with-comments/#pull-request-comments

Comment: I have a really silly doubt: If I have a pull request numbered 1 and an issue numbered 1, if I use this API, will it comment on the issue or the PR?

Comment: @deborah-digges That will never happen because issues and pull requests share the numbers. In other words, if you create an issue in a repository and a pull request after that, the issue will get number 1 and the pull request will get the number 2.

Comment: Thanks @JustinHarris. This makes sense. Would it make sense to say that PR is a subclass of issue?

Comment: @deborah-digges Yeah, I guess you could say that if that helps with understanding. But I think it would be even better if you just ask about the specific problems you're seeing instead of making conclusions based on the general assumption that one is a subclass of another. Also feel free to ask questions using the contact form: https://github.com/contact

Comment: Thanks for the help, @IvanZuzak. I'll definitely send in questions :-)